# Redirected `ansible-doc -s` output gets weirdly formatted

Tags: ansible

I'm preparing for Ansible certification, and I decided that `ansible-doc -s` may be useful to speed up creation of playbooks.  It dumps a snippet of configuration of the requested module, with all options and comments describing them, like so:

```
$ansible-doc -s file

- name: Manage files and file properties
  file:
      access_time:           # This parameter indicates the time the file's access time should be set to. Should be `preserve' when no modification is required,
                               `YYYYMMDDHHMM.SS' when using default time format, or `now'. Default is `None' meaning that `preserve' is
                               the default for `state=[file,directory,link,hard]' and `now' is default for `state=touch'.
      access_time_format:    # When used with `access_time', indicates the time format that must be used. Based on default Python format (see time.strftime doc).
      attributes:            # The attributes the resulting file or directory should have. To get supported flags look at the man page for `chattr' on the target
                               system. This string should contain the attributes in the same order as the one displayed by `lsattr'. The
(...)
```

I then learn that I can easily insert that into a file on `vim`, using something like `:r! ansible-doc -s file`.  Except that, when I do that, the file gets weirdly formatted:

```
- name: Manage files and file properties
  file:
      access_time:           # This parameter indicates the time the file's
                               access time
                               should be set to.
                               Should be
                               `preserve' when
                               no modification
                               is required,
(...)
```

If I was to fix that formatting, I'd lose time instead of saving it.

I have noticed that it is not a `vim` thing; if I pipe the output of `ansible-doc` or redirect it to a file, the same happens.  I tried setting `PAGER=cat`, to not avail; it respects that environment variable and replaces `less` with `cat`, but still changes the formatting.

Apparently, whenever `ansible-doc` sees a non-tty stdout, it *uglifies* the output.  Anybody knows how to fix that?